# How to NOT repeat a random number in a for loop?

Tags: php, html, css

I have this PHP for loop. It creates a random number.

```
for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($query); $i++) {
$random = rand(000, 999);
}
```

I want that the `for` never repeats the result of the random. The `for` run 999 times and I want that it never repeats the result of the `for`.

Comment: Huh? Do you want to loop "random" times?

Comment: In your code, the `for` will only run based on the number of results, not necessarily 999 times.

Comment: add items into an array and do a check to make sure that the item doesn't exist in the array already

Comment: Before the loop, create an array; fill the array with values 0 - 999 and then randomise the array. Then in the loop, use the i'th array element. Pray that there will never be more than 1000 rows.

Comment: Start with an array `range(0,999)`, call `shuffle()` on it, then just iterate over it sequentially.

Comment: Well, you should store the values already generated in an array, and each time compare the randomly generated value with each value of the array. But be carefull, it can soon become a ressource problem, especially as the range of your random numbers gets closer to the number of results of your query...

Comment: This question may need more information pertaining to the current implementation and end result.

Comment: @Yve - Whilst normally I would agree, in this case it was clear that the OP meant `repeat` when he said `ripite` and `random` for `ramdom`.

Comment: @Yve - Yeah, just saw what you meant then. I just replaced all instances, didn't look at context. Notepad++ for the loss :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shuffle()` is probably the best option but if you for some reason don't want to do that here is another option:

```
$max_value = 999;
$values = range(0, $max_value);
$counter = $max_value;
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query); //Best to move this out of the for loop so it doesn't recalculate every time through
for($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++){
    $rand_num = rand(0,$counter);
    $current_number = $values[$rand_num];
    array_splice($values, $rand_num, 1);
    $counter--;
    echo "rand number: " . $current_number . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: +1. (instead of the for loop at the top use `range(1, 999)`), but this is the fastest possible I think.

Answer (score 6):

I would not use a `for` loop and tracking array. Instead create an array with your range of values and shuffle it.

```
$random_numbers = range(0, 999);
shuffle($random_numbers);
```

Now you can pop items off this array with the guarantee they are unique. Use [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) if you need to format the output as `000`, `001`, etc.

Comment: `shuffle()` is another example of PHP's inconsistent behaviour. It does return a bool and change the array that was passed by reference.

Comment: @str, between that and needle, haystack, I'm surprised I haven't gone insane.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary True. Object oriented types and method chaining would these things so much easier.

Comment: @Lars Stegelitz, so long as the range is reasonably small.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary that's why I used array_rand in my answer. It's faster than shuffle.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary whut? this is the efficientest way I can think of to use array_rand?! tell me an more efficient way, please.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary oh, xD (should make attention to my English, even if I'm a bit tired :-P) … but then "this is the most efficient way I can think of to use array_rand"

Answer (score 1):

```
$randomArray = array_rand(range(0, 999), $size = mysql_num_rows($query));

for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    $random = $randomArray[$i];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski this was my intention. range(0, x) produces an array with the keys from 0 to x. (where key = value). So I have random, not repeating, values in $randomArray.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are a couple ways to do it.  You can do this in the MySQL query itself.  Just use:

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY RAND()
```

This is not the fastest solution, but it works and you can just iterate through the data.
If you don't want to do that, you need to shuffle the array like the other solutions suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
$randomArray = range(0, $count);
shuffle($randomArray);

for ($i = 0, $j = $count; $i < $j; $i++) {
    $random = array_shift($randomArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for below code

```
function nonRepeat($min,$max,$count) {


    if($max - $min < $count) {
        return false;
    }

   $nonrepeatarray = array();
   for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
      $rand = rand($min,$max);


      while(in_array($rand,$nonrepeatarray)) {
        $rand = rand($min,$max);
      }

      //add it to the array
      $nonrepeatarray[$i] = $rand;
   }
   return $nonrepeatarray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$results=new array();
for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($query); $i++){
     $random = rand(000, 999);
     if(!in_array($random,$results) {
           array_push($results,$random);
     }
}
// you can print_r($results) here if you want
```

Comment: While all random numbers will different in `$result`, it will probably generate less than the expected amount of random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the entropy level - or generate a random one based on time. PHP.net has a good example:

```
// seed with microseconds
function make_seed() {
  list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
  return (float) $sec + ((float) $usec * 100000);
}
srand(make_seed());
$randval = rand();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$random_values = array();
for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($query); $i++){
    $random = rand(000, 999);
    while(in_array($random, $random_values)) $random = rand(000, 999);
        $random_values[] = $random;
}
```

Comment: Once again, if I'm not mistaken, can easily lead to an infinite loop. Cfr answer from qwerty below